# Custom wordpress php page, show not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a static php page to allow our clubs event system to work properly with wordpress as it has to pass variables. It works just fine apart from one problem.

If I'm logged into wordpress and I then visit my calendar.php page here "http://www.dsac.co.uk/calendar.php" the sidebar shows me as not being logged in.

I used

```
<?php
require('wordpress/wp-load.php');
get_header();
?>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">

php stuff

?>
</div>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Ignore the login button above the calendar, I'm in the process of making it check and see if the user is logged into wordpress instead of a separate login which is how I discovered this problem.

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have `require('wordpress/wp-load.php');` in your code? If you make a custom page template this is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
<?php 
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-load.php'; // Taking into consideration that the "wp-load.php" file is in the same folder of the file you're using
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
if(is_user_logged_in()){
   echo "User is logged in";
} else {
   echo "User is not logged in";
}
?>
```